# Exclude site from Datadog automatic trace instrumentation on IIS

Tags: .net, iis, trace, datadog, distributed-tracing

I was wondering to know if there is a way to exclude a site from Datadog automatic tracing on IIS. I've read the docs but didn't find anything about.

Comment: Not sure what you exactly mean by site. APM needs to be enabled manually on an app. What is the context you are working on?

In the meantime, if you are looking for some obfuscation [this doc](https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/setup_overview/configure_data_security/?tab=mongodb#exclude-resources-from-being-collected) could help.

Comment: Hi, a site on IIS. The APM with .NET framework on IIS has automatic instrumentation so all sites hosted are monitored by default. I need to specify sites to be exluded from this automatic monitoring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Datadog's .NET Tracer, you can set `DD_TRACE_ENABLED=false` in the `appSettings` section of the `web.config` file ([docs](https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/setup_overview/setup/dotnet-framework/?tab=webconfig#configuration)). For example:

```xml
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="DD_TRACE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Another option is to deploy a `datadog.json` file ([docs](https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/setup_overview/setup/dotnet-framework/?tab=jsonfile#configuration)) in the root of your app that contains:

```json
{
    "DD_TRACE_ENABLED": "false"
}
```

(Disclaimer: I work at Datadog)

Answer (score 0):

Datadog’s IIS integration queries the Web Service performance counters automatically and sends the results to Datadog. The Web Service performance counter class collects information from the World Wide Web Publishing Service.

You can enable the IIS integration by creating a configuration file either manually or through the Datadog Agent GUI. To create a configuration file through the GUI, navigate to the “Checks” tab, choose “Manage Checks,” and select the iis check from the “Add a Check” menu. You can also manually create a conf.yaml file in C:\ProgramData\Datadog\conf.d\iis.d.

There is a sites attribute in the conf.yaml file. This attribute represents the IIS site you want to monitor. You only need to delete the sites you want to exclude.

More information you can refer to this link: [IIS monitoring with Datadog](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/iis-monitoring-datadog/).

Comment: Hello samwu, this is related to DataDog software, not Oracle APM. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for not understanding your question, I re-edited my answer, hope this can help you.