# Do Datadog has the ability to exclude some of the websites from profiling?

Tags: profiling, datadog

Do Datadog has the ability to exclude some of the websites from profiling?
ie, Suppose client has 10 websites hosted in IIS but he needs only 3 websites to be profiled.Is it possible to do so?
Any help is highly appreciated :)

Comment: What specific Datadog product are you using? The answer varies between products, for example, the Java Continuous Profiler and the .NET Tracer.

Comment: .net tracer is the one I am looking for

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exclude site from DataDog automatic trace instrumentation on IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66443203/exclude-site-from-datadog-automatic-trace-instrumentation-on-iis)

Comment: @Lucas Yes,Thankyou